# Find all functions $f$ and $g$ for which $f(x+y) = g(xy)$.

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions $f$ and $g$ for which $f(x+y) = g(xy)$.

Is there anything wrong with this?

We see that $f(1) =g(0)$ and $f(0) = g(0)$ so $f(1) = f(0)$. Also, $f(x) = g(0)$ and therefore $f(x) = f(1)$ and so $f$ must be constant? Similarly $g(x) = f(x+1) = f(1)$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Both functions must be constant and equals

Comment: $f(x+0) = f(x) = g(0)$ for all $x$, hence $f$ is a constant ($g(0)$). Then $g(x) = f(x+1) = g(0)$, so $g$ is a constant too.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your reasoning. Your presentation is somewhat unclear though. For instance,  I assume your reasoning is to say
$$f(1+0)=g(1\cdot 0)$$
but you only write $f(1)=g(0)$, which is not as clear. One might also note that one can combine the steps by saying
$$f(x+0)=g(x\cdot 0)=g(0)=g(y\cdot 0)=f(y+0)$$
which gives $f$ to be constant. Then $g(x\cdot 1)=f(x+1)$ gives $g$ to be constant.